# Trigger 'drop' event while providing the file data

Tags: javascript, dom-events

**Question**

How could I, while providing the file, trigger a `drop` event of a field, on which *I do not have access at loading*.

**Details**

There is a page with a field on which is attached a `drop` listener that process an image when dropped. I would like to be able to use this process by *pasting* an image. I know how to get the file from a paste, but I do not know how to dispatch a `drop` event that would contains this very file.

The obstacles are:

- The code is obfuscated, I cannot access the function linked with the listener by name.
- There is no way to get the `drop` listener after it being attached to an element. *It seems there is some way to do it in the console, but not from a script.*
- I do not control the page rendering; i.e. I cannot intercept the event listener addition.
- Vanilla Javascript & could only work in Chrome (extension).
- This page is built in vanilla; i.e. no jQuery or anything.

Does anyone have an idea on how to tackle this task?

I am looking into [DragEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent/DragEvent) but *"although this interface has a constructor, it is not possible to create a useful DataTransfer object from script, since DataTransfer objects have a processing and security model that is coordinated by the browser during drag-and-drops."*

I saw a possible approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/39066443/1004274 but I want to mimic a *real* drop event with its data, i.e. pass a file I got via `clipboardData.items[0].getAsFile();` instead of just text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fake the **drop** event, and fake pretty much everything that's in there. What you'll have problem doing is triggering a default event, such as opening a file in a tab by dropping it. The reason isn't so much because of the **dataTransfer** object being protected, but the event not being trusted. By having trusted event and protected dataTransfer, you can be sure you won't pass data to a trusted event, and that you won't trigger default event with unwanted data.

But depending on how the drop function is accessing the file that is dropped, you might be able to trick it with a fake **drop** event and a fake **dataTransfer** object. See this fiddle for a general idea of how it may work:

```
var a = document.getElementById('link');
var dropZone1 = document.getElementById('dropZone1');
var dropZone2 = document.getElementById('dropZone2');
var fakeDropBtn = document.getElementById('fakeDropBtn');

dropZone1.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});

dropZone2.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});

dropZone1.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
  // This first drop zone is simply to get access to a file.
  // In your case the file would come from the clipboard
  // but you need to work with an extension to have access
  // to paste data, so here I use a drop event
  e.preventDefault();
  fakeDropBtn.classList.remove('disabled');
  dropZone2.classList.remove('disabled');
  var fileToDrop = e.dataTransfer.files[0];

  // You create a drop event
  var fakeDropEvent = new DragEvent('drop');
  // You override dataTransfer with whichever property
  // and method the drop function needs
  Object.defineProperty(fakeDropEvent, 'dataTransfer', {
    value: new FakeDataTransfer(fileToDrop)
  });

  fakeDropBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // the fake event will be called on the button click
    dropZone2.dispatchEvent(fakeDropEvent);
  });
});



dropZone2.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  // this is the fake event being called. In this case for 
  // example, the function gets access to dataTransfer files.
  // You'll see the result will be the same with a real
  // drop event or with a fake drop event. The only thing
  // that matters is to override the specific property this function
  // is using.
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.dataTransfer.files[0]);
  a.href = url;
  a.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url); 
});

function FakeDataTransfer(file) {
  this.dropEffect = 'all';
  this.effectAllowed = 'all';
  this.items = [];
  this.types = ['Files'];
  this.getData = function() {

    return file;
  };
  this.files = [file];
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5m2u0tux/6/

Comment: Thanks a lot. _"The only thing that matters is to override the specific property this function is using."_ That is my biggest problem because the drop listener is part of a big framework. That would be a lot of work to find what is actually used, and I wish not to depend on it.

Comment: Anyway, that should help me to go on.

Comment: Knowing which method to override will simplify the approach, but you should be able to make a complete fake dataTransfer, there's not that many methods and properties. Except if the function relies on default actions, it should work.

Comment: @oldergod did you ever get it to work on the site you were testing the code on?  For me, it doesn't fire a drop event at all (I set breakpoints in chrome inspector) and nothing happens. Any advice?

Comment: @travisjayday I actually don't remember but cannot find anything of that sort in my repos so probably didn't succeed.

Comment: Thanks @oldergod. I got it working, so for anyone with the same problem: generating a fake event either did not trigger a "drop" or datatansfer object was always set to null. The solution was to create a Drag event with document.createEvent and use object.properties to override the datatansfer property. Then, this worked from the console but not from the script for some reason. So to make it work from the script, I injected a button with inline js into the DOM that fires the event. The solution is super hacky and I'm not really proud of it, but hey, it's the only one that worked for me :-)

Comment: Your solution has helped me with something similar at work. Thank you very much!