# How to simulate a dataTransfer object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I would like to simulate a file drop on a window.
I can replace the File object with a Blob.

To launch the event, I use `zone.dispatchEvent(new DragEvent('drop', {dataTransfer: __________}))`

The problem is that we cannot create a DataTransfer object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer : "It cannot be created separately (i.e. there is no constructor for this object).").

I would like to make a false DataTransfer object. When I try {} or anything, I get "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'DragEvent': member dataTransfer is not of type DataTransfer.".

Is it possible to override that? Or is it a security measure?

Comment: I assume you mean {} where the ____ is in your post?  I think you could create a replica of the entire thing, but you need to experiment a bit...  For example: try prototype chaining.  Or create the object from scratch setting up your own constructor to match types etc...  Have you tried anything besides the object literal?

Comment: Yes for {}. I tried the converse: making a DataTransfer not recognized anymore by overriding its __proto__ but it did not worked. I would like to know what method they use to verify the type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028875/how-to-trigger-an-event-with-a-custom-event-specifically-a-custom-datatransfer

Comment: I swear I searched for over 30 minutes on google and SO! Thank you Ted!